# SQL parameter inside my Where clause no return

Tags: sql

I have this stored procedure that have a Where condition.

```
    create proc TRYLANG
    @param1 varchar(20),
    @param2 varchar(20)
    as
   begin
   select * from [Reference].[tbl_FilterBy]
   where @param1 = @param2
   end
```

But when I execute the stored procedure, it returns no rows. help! what is my mistake?

Comment: You cannot use parameters to specify the **column name** in your `WHERE` clause (`@param1`). If you have to have this, you need to use **dynamic SQL** (assuming you're talking about SQL Server)

Comment: What is in the two parameter? You really want to check their equality?

Comment: Param1 contains column name and Param2 contains the actual value in the row.

Answer (score 0):

@param1 = @param2 ?? Try :

```
create proc TRYLANG
    @param1 varchar(20),
    @param2 varchar(20)
    as
   begin
   select * from [Reference].[tbl_FilterBy]
   where yourcolumnName = @param1 and  yourcolumnName = @param2
   end
```

Check table has a value. and you are in correct database.

Comment: I don't think so. According to him, Param1 contains column name and Param2 contains the actual value in the row..

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to query ?
you are passing two parameters and just comparing them together !

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot pass the Column name by parameters and maybe you're trying to check various columns, try this;

```
create proc TRYLANG
    @param1 varchar(20)
    as
   begin
   select * from [Reference].[tbl_FilterBy]
   where Column1 = @param1
   or    Column2 = @param1
   or    Column3 = @param1 // All your possible column you need to check
   end
```